# Как задать имя процесса перед его стартом

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

У меня **есть программа, которую я упаковываю в .exe**

**Мне нужно задать названия процессов**, которые запускаются так:

```
import multiprocessing
p_out, p_in = multiprocessing.Pipe()
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=Test, args=(p_in,))
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=Test2, args=(p_out,))
p1.start()
p2.start()
```

**Желательно изменить название и основного процесса** *(С которого и запускаются остальные)*

Все процессы имеют названия запускаемого .exe, **как изменить название процессов не зависимо от названия исполняемого файла?**

*p.s всё это запускается на Windows*

Comment: Попробуйте https://pypi.org/project/setproctitle/

Comment: @PakUula, я получаю ошибку при установки библиотеки:
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2

Comment: У меня Python 3.7 32-х битный. Собралось легко и непринуждённо, но эффект нулевой. Рецепты `ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW("My New Title")` и `os.system("title My new title")` тоже не помогли. TaskManager в Windows 10 упорно показывает Python32.